# How to Call WCF Rest Service From Php

Tags: php, wcf, wcf-binding

Hi  i am not used to Php , I have Created a WCF Rest Service, can any one telme how to call that service from php code

Thanks

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and the Url.  It is rest ;)